# Rails 3.2.1 heroku asset precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have added these two lines to application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

config.assets.compile = true
```

However I still get errors when I push to Heroku:

```
2012-02-05T09:48:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2012-02-05T09:48:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-05T09:48:34+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does heroku say when it tries to precompile your assets (are you on cedar?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the looks of it you have a `bootstrap.css` file that is not included properly in your manifest file within `app/assets/stylesheets` and that you're probably also calling directly from a `stylesheet_tag`.

There are a couple of approaches to this:

1. You could add a line to your environment config file which will ensure the css file you're calling is precompiled:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.css )`

…for example.

2. This is the one i would probably do; include the bootstrap.css file in a manifest file inside `app/assets/stylesheets' as mentioned above. Your manifest file will look something like this (not sure if the formatting of this will appear correctly on here, so i have also created a Gist: https://gist.github.com/1753229):

/*
*= require bootstrap
*/

/* rest of file omitted */

You might need to require more files than that depending on what your css setup is.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `rake assets:precompile` before committing your code and pushing it to heroku.

Answer (score 3):

read [this](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html), it's a tutorial on how to get rails 3.2.1 (and ruby 1.9.3) running on heroku. You can obviously skip the bits you don't need but it should explain why these problems are happening and how to fix them.

Also, read [this](http://davidjrice.co.uk/2012/01/19/upgrading-to-ruby-1-9-and-rails-3-2.html) article by david rice, author of the useful asset_sync gem. It will help you sort this out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of those links. Both were really helpful for getting my app up to speed. Unfortunately neither has helped me sort out the pre-compilation errors, which I am still getting. Any other places I could try?

Comment: take a look at zoltarSpeaks's answer, it sounds promising